# Login failed for root from 190.20.86.0. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, imap, roundcube

I have been dealing for over twelve hours looking for a solution with my Roundcube installation in my Virtual Private Server, Ubuntu 16.04. The IMAP (dovecot) and SMTP servers are online and can `telnet` without connection refused errors.

However, when I go to my webmail and try to login with username `root` and the relevant SSH/SFTP password (in order to test if it is working, then I will create additional email addresses), it returns the following error:

```
IMAP Error in /usr/share/nginx/roundcubemail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php (193): Login failed for root from 190.20.86.0. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed * BYE.
```

The `/var/log/nginx/mail.log` and the `/var/log/nginx/roundcube.error` are empty

How do I solve this issue while trying to login?

Comment: Do not use `root`.  Much software is configured not to let root login.

Comment: How do I create additional email addresses in Roundcube?

Comment: Please ask on a site dedicated to software configuration such as our sister sites: superuser or serverfault.  Stack Overflow is specifically geared to programming questions.